# Sor Estudio 6: third section fingering / position

Tags: fingering, classical-guitar

Here is an excerpt from Sor's Estudio #6

[image]

I would like to understand the fingering and positions used for the two or three measures beginning at the indicated starting point.
As written in the sheet music, the two A's are played on the second string, so the fourth finger of my fretting hand is on the tenth fret.
How long do we stay in that position? What positions should be used in the following measures?

Comment: Just those 3 As, as indicated by the line over them.  Then you go back to 1st position.

Comment: Playing in that position is just one editor's idea.  It's a slightly easier stretch.  Sor did not mark it that way; his fingerings are less detailed.

Comment: It is worth bearing in mind that sometimes composers or editors indicate a certain fingering because they feel that the notes fall more naturally under the fingers that way, but sometimes they choose a certain fingering (on a different string) because of the different tonal effect. In this case, I think it sounds nicer with the A played high up on the 2nd string (a little more mellow, compared to the brighter sound on the 1st string), but then you get a long shift back ready to play the C natural also on the 2nd string. Needs more practice this way, but probably worth it for the tone quality.

Comment: Thanks, @OldJohn. I do understand that fingering depends on both physical possibility and tone. In this piece I was puzzled by the annotations because it suggests a pretty big jump in position and was therefore curious how others would handle it.

Comment: On youtube videos the big jump seems to be the minority choice.

Comment: I found a Kevin Gallagher lesson using this Segovia edition.  He mentions briefly this high position option, and suggests the choice has to do with vibrato.

Comment: There is also a R Dyens masterclass video that focuses on the slide back to 1st position (but in French).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can play the high 'a' as indicated on the second string and move back to the first position for the second part of the measure. You could also play the first half of the measure in the second position, playing the high 'a' on the fifth fret of the e-string. I would probably choose this latter option. The next bar is in the first position. So is the first half of the first bar in the next line. In the second half of that bar you need to move to the third position. The second bar of that line starts in the second position (I would play the second note - a 'C' - with my second finger, not with my third finger as indicated). The second half of that bar is played in the first position.

As a general remark, fingerings are recommendations. Many times there are alternative fingerings that sound as good or even better, and that may be more practical for you, so keep on experimenting. If you can't discuss these things with an experienced teacher, try to find a video or at least an audio recording to see and hear how a seasoned player plays the piece you're working on.

Answer (score -2):

Great question! Play until string 2 is no longer notated atop the measure. After that, usually, if you don't see string numbers or capo markings, it's most likely first position.